# Get CSRF Token from response header after making http requests

Tags: go

I want to make a request to a certain website but to do this I need to first make a post request to one part of the site and then grab the CSRF token from the headers for me to use in my second request. In a language like python this is really easy to do with the use of sessions and the ability to use requests module to grab the headers but I cant seem to find anything about this online for me to do it in Go. Any ideas? All the google search's just return how to set a token when making a website.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example would be useful, it is not websites like others.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/csrf"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    csrfMiddleware := csrf.Protect([]byte("32-byte-long-auth-key"))

    api := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
    api.Use(csrfMiddleware)
    api.HandleFunc("/user/{id}", GetUser).Methods("GET")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}

func GetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Authenticate the request, get the id from the route params,
    // and fetch the user from the DB, etc.

    // Get the token and pass it in the CSRF header. Our JSON-speaking client
    // or JavaScript framework can now read the header and return the token in
    // in its own "X-CSRF-Token" request header on the subsequent POST.
    w.Header().Set("X-CSRF-Token", csrf.Token(r))
    b, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    w.Write(b)
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/gorilla/csrf#javascript-applications

Comment: See I am not wanting to make my own web server and use CSRF tokens I am wanting to make a HTTP request to a website but the website is blocking me because it requires a csrf token, now I can get one in the response headers on a part of the website but I dont have a clue how I can set that value to a variable (I want to parse the response headers from a web page)